# nginx and php-fpm in Docker

Tags: php, nginx, docker, boot2docker, fig

I am in the process of *Dockerising* my webserver/php workflow.

But because I am on Windows, I need to use a virtual machine. I chose boot2docker which is a Tiny Core Linux running in Virtualbox and adapted for Docker.

I selected three containers:

- [nginx](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/nginx/): the official nginx container;
- [jprjr/php-fpm](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/jprjr/php-fpm/): a php-fpm container;
- [mysql](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/): for databases.

In boot2docker, `/www/` contains my web projects and `conf/`, which has the following tree:

```
conf
│
├───fig
│       fig.yml
│
└───nginx
        nginx.conf
        servers-global.conf
        servers.conf
```

Because `docker-compose` is not available for boot2docker, I must use `fig` to automate everything. Here is my `fig.xml`:

```
mysql:
 image: mysql
 environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
 ports:
  - 3306:3306

php:
 image: jprjr/php-fpm
 links:
  - mysql:mysql
 volumes:
  - /www:/srv/http:ro
 ports:
  - 9000:9000

nginx:
 image: nginx
 links:
  - php:php
 volumes:
  - /www:/www:ro
 ports:
  - 80:80
 command: nginx -c /www/conf/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Here is my `nginx.conf`:

```
daemon off;

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        off;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    index    index.php index.html index.htm;

    include /www/conf/nginx/servers.conf;

    autoindex on;
}
```

And the `servers.conf`:

```
server {
    server_name lab.dev;
    root /www/lab/;

    include /www/conf/nginx/servers-global.conf;
}

# Some other servers (vhosts)
```

And the `servers-global.conf`:

```
listen 80;

location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    php:9000;
    include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     /srv/http$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

So the problem now (sorry for all that configuration, I believe it was needed to clearly explain the problem): If I access `lab.dev`, no problem (which shows that the host is created in Windows) but if I try to access `lab.dev/test_autoload/`, I have a `File not found.`. I know this comes from `php-fpm` not being able to access the files, and the nginx logs confirm this:

```
nginx_1 | 2015/05/28 14:56:02 [error] 5#5: *3 FastCGI sent in stderr:
"Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream,
client: 192.168.59.3, server: lab.dev, request: "GET /test_autoload/ HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "fastcgi://172.17.0.120:9000", host: "lab.dev", referrer: "http://lab.dev/"
```

I know that there is a `index.php` in `lab/test_autoload/` in both containers, I have checked. In `nginx`, it is located in `/www/lab/test_autoload/index.php` and `/srv/http/lab/test_autoload/index.php` in `php`.

I believe the problem comes from `root` and/or `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME`, but I do not know how to solve it.

I have tried many things, such as modifying the `root`s, using a `rewrite` rule, adding/removing some `/`s, etc, but nothing has made it change.

Again, sorry for all this config, but I think it was needed to describe the environment I am in.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that docker-compose does not work with boot2docker. It does just fine.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/599) and [there](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1032), sadly.

Comment: Oh I see, you're trying to install it in boot2docker directly. You could always run docker-compose inside a new container, I'm sure that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

The variable `$fastcgi_script_name` did not take into account the root (logical, as it would have included `www/` otherwise. This means that a global file can not work. An example :

```
# "generated" vhost
server {
    server_name lab.dev;
    root /www/lab/;

    listen 80;

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass    php:9000;
        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     /srv/http$fastcgi_script_name;
        # I need to add /lab after /srv/http because it requests PHP to look at the root of the web files, not in the lab/ folder
        # fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     /srv/http/lab$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

This meant that I couldn't write the `lab/` at only one place, I needed to write at two different places (root and fastcgi_param) so I decided to write myself a small PHP script that used a `.json` and turned it into the `servers.conf` file. If anyone wants to have a look at it, just ask, it will be a pleasure to share it.

Comment: Asking for sharing the file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did a reinstall and I don't use PHP anymore (nor Docker). :|

Comment: So you don't have the `servers.conf` file any more?

Comment: No, sorry. It was just, as shown in the question, a list of virtual hosts, all looking similar to the one shown. And for the script, it just took the data from the JSON (would recommand YAML now) and filled in a template.

Answer (score 1):

There's a mistake here:

```
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     /srv/http/$fastcgi_script_name;
```

The good line is:

```
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     /srv/http$fastcgi_script_name;
```

This is not the same thing.

Comment: My bad. This is one of the many tests I did, even with `/srv/http$fastcgi_script_name`, it doesn't work. I'll edit the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx.conf is fully empty, where is the daemon off;
the user nginx line, worker_processes etc.. nginx need some configuration file before running the http.

In the http conf, same thing, is missing the mime types, the default_type, configuration of logs sendfile at on for boot2docker.

Your problem is clearly not a problem with Docker, but with the nginx configuration. Have you test your application with running docker run before using fig ? Did it worked ?

Comment: I have edited the OP to show my entire nginx. As I said, I can access `lab.dev` (I see the list of folders, because of `autoindex on`), which shows that my configuration is fonctionnal, apart for when I want to access a folder's `index.php` by calling the folder.